# Point free function gives different result to non-point free?

Tags: haskell

I'm working through CIS194 to learn me some Haskell.

I have a data type `Stream`, which can be created from a seed using `streamFromSeed` function.

```
data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)

instance Show a => Show (Stream a) where
    show (Cons a s) = show $ take 10 $ streamToList s

streamToList :: Stream a -> [a]
streamToList (Cons a s) = a:(streamToList s)

streamFromSeed :: (a -> a) -> a -> Stream a
streamFromSeed f a = Cons a (streamFromSeed f (f a))
```

So far so good, so I create a `Stream` in ghci:

```
*Main> streamFromSeed (\x -> x+1) 0
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

This is a bit strange to me - I expected `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.

So I change `Show` instance to this:

```
instance Show a => Show (Stream a) where
    show = show . take 10 . streamToList
```

And sure enough:

```
*Main> streamFromSeed (\x -> x+1) 0
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

What's going on here? Why are those two `show` implementations different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your point-free version is equivalent to this:

```
show s = show $ take 10 $ streamToList s
```

Here `s` refers to the whole stream and you then take the first 10 items of it. This will produce the expected result. What you did was:

```
show (Cons a s) = show $ take 10 $ streamToList s
```

Here `a` refers to the first element of the stream and `s` to the rest of the stream (the tail). You then take the first 10 elements of that tail, not the whole stream.

Comment: @zoran119 Note that there's no reason to pattern match on the stream, so `show s = show $ take 10 $ streamToList s` would work fine. The point-free version follows easily from that definition.